# Get line coordinates for vertical lines numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have detected horizontal and vertical lines in this picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

src = cv.imread("filename.png", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

if len(src.shape) != 2:
    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray = src

gray = cv.bitwise_not(gray)
bw = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)

horizontal = np.copy(bw)
vertical = np.copy(bw)

cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = int(cols / 30)

horizontalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))
horizontal = cv.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)

#np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
cv.imwrite("img_horizontal8.png", horizontal)

h_transpose = np.transpose(np.nonzero(horizontal))
print("h_transpose")
print(h_transpose[:100])
#prints [ 56  35] ... [ 56  134]
#and that makes sense, there is an horizontal line more or less in the height 56 like that on the image img_horizontal8.png



rows = vertical.shape[0]
verticalsize = int(rows / 30)
verticalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
vertical = cv.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)

cv.imwrite("img_vertical8.png", vertical)

v_transpose = np.transpose(np.nonzero(vertical))

print("v_transpose")
print(v_transpose[:100])

prints:

 [  68  489]
 [  68  490]
 [  69  489]
 [  69  490]
 [  69  721]
 [  70  489]
 [  70  490]
 [  70  721]
 [  71  489]
 [  71  490]
 [  71  721]
 [  71  950]
 [  72  489]
 [  72  490]
 [  72  721]
 [  72  950]
 [  73  489]
 [  73  490]
 [  73  721]
 [  73  950]
 [  74  489]
 [  74  490]
 [  74  721]
 [  74  950]
 [  75  489]
 [  75  490]
 [  75  721]
 [  75  950]
 [  75 1179]
 [  75 1410]
 [  76  489]
 [  76  490]
 [  76  721]
 [  76  950]
 [  76 1178]
 [  76 1179]
 [  76 1410]
 [  77  489]
 [  77  490]
 [  77  721]
 [  77  950]
 [  77 1178]
 [  77 1179]
 [  77 1410]
 [  78  489]
 [  78  490]
 [  78  721]
 [  78  950]
 [  78 1178]
 [  78 1179]
 [  78 1410]
```

Am I misunderstanding something about getting the coordinates for the vertical lines? The printed results seem to show we have a line from 68,489 to 68,490 (line with length 1) and then a bunch of other very short lines up to the point where x=78. But on the image img_vertical8.png there are no extremely short lines visible, so I don´t get what´s going on. Are these arrays for the vertical lines maybe wrong for some reason? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

What you're printing out are the pixel coordinates of the mostly-black-with-white-stripes images that you produce. They don't have any connectivity information associated with them, so you shouldn't assume that two pixels that are adjacent in the list you produce actually have a line between them.

I think the thing you're getting confused by is the fact that `np.nonzero` is effectively sorting the data that you're printing out. By "sort", I mean that its return value will always contain first the indices of the nonzero values in the `0`th row, then the nonzero values in the `1`st row, and so forth.

Think about it kind of like an old CRT monitor (if you're old enough to know what that is): `nonzero` is scanning horizontally across your image, successively catching pixels from lines that are parallel to one another, not connected.

## The solution

You can further process your images of vertical lines and horizontal lines in order to get the actual lines you want. Following the instructions I found [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html), I made the following image by finding and then drawing line segments back onto the original newspaper image:

[image]

Here's the code I used (which builds off of where your code stops):

```
img = src.copy()

# edges = cv.Canny(vertical,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 200
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(vertical,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv.imwrite('houghlinesP_vert.jpg', img)
```

Comment: This looks good. I am impressed. But do you know why the bottom line, second from right is not detected by the HoughLinesP? That line is among the original vertical lines.

Comment: You can fiddle the with the `minLineLength ` and `maxLineGap ` parameters to change which lines get drawn. For example, setting those both to `100` will make it so that particular line does get drawn. You're going to have to play around with `HoughLinesP ` (and maybe more importantly your preprocessing routine) in order to make it so that all lines are reliably and robustly recognized.

Comment: The "robustly" requirement tends to be the tricky part with image recognition algorithms. For example, will your code still work if it was an image of white text on a black sheet of paper? I actually had a somewhat similar challenge sprung on me once at short notice.

Comment: is there a way that i can get the bounding box values for the vertical lines ?